# How to assign predefined values to millions of records in MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, database

This is my concern:

I have a mysql table (`main_table`) with different columns (`id`, `reg_date`, `time` etc). It has about 30 million rows and grows.

Recently I found that I need to assign an additional list/table of 1550 different names (e.g. `"Michael Flowers"`, `"Dora Dorn"`, etc.) to the table.

Which name will be assigned to which row is not important, so I can use a random id function. But the name should always be the same when queried from the `main_table` row.

The most straightforward solution would be to alter the `main_table` and then insert a random value from 1 to 1550 (e.g. 10) for each row. However, I hesitate to do this due the fact I think it would cause performance issues. Another reason is that the number of rows are growing continuously so I may need to add some batch processing.

The only restriction is that once assigned a name to a specific row it should always return the same name.  For example if I assign `"Michael Flowers"` (which will have an id anywhere from 1 to 1550, e.g. 10) to a row from the main table (e.g. 30000), I need to be able to always retrieve the same name when I check for the row 30000.

Therefore I'm thinking if it would be possible to create a function/algorithm which would make each row from the `main_table` to map to a name from the 1550 available names, like

```
echo name_of_row(30000);  
// result would be 10, I may then query and my list and find it's Michael Flowers
```

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?  Also tl;dr.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this, but couldn't you solve this with an auxiliary table that stores these "additional" 1550 names and then reference them in the main table with a foreign key? That's if I understood this, I'm not sure I did...

Comment: All fixed, except for the question. I assume it is "How do I get what I describe?", though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your new names table has consecutive ID numbers from 1 -> 1500, then you could simply add a new integer field to your main table and do

```
UPDATE main_table SET linkfield = FLOOR(1 + (rand() * 1550))
```

MySQL's rand function isn't of crytopgraphic quality, but it'd certainly do a good enough job in this case.

Then you get get the main_table's random name value with a simple join:

```
SELECT main_table.*, name_table.name
FROM main_table
LEFT JOIN name_table.id = main_table.linkfield
```

Comment: thank for your response . However you may find that updating millions of records takes some time so I don't think it's a reliable solution .

Comment: @Michael: But you would do it only *once*. I really can't see what the problem is.

Comment: @Michael: it'll be far more reliable than any other hacked-in solution.